# How to know a ball park figure for a salary before going for the interview?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, salary, hiring-process

I have started to look for a new job, couple of weeks ago An internal recuriter of a company called me for a interview , the vacancy was posted at linkedin and i applied for it.

The vacancy did not had any salary indication, Long story short I went for the interview every thing went well and during the Hr discussion they offered the salary which was same what i am getting right now and I said no.

I applied for another position two days back via linkedin , the vacancy looked promising and have no salary indication. Today the Hr Personal of the company called and invited me for the interview. It is a full day process, I would like to know is there any ball park figures for this position . I do not want to sound greedy at the same time I would like to make it worth. since it disappointing to see when you go through the process and in the end the salarys do not match.

I currently work in netherland.

Comment: @gnat This is not about knowing what is reasonable to ask for. Ankur seems to already have a idea what he wants to earn. He want to know whatever the company is willing to offer that salary so he does not go to a full day interview, only to find out at the end that they are not willing to pay him what he wants.

Comment: Please, add the Netherlands tag to your question. I would advise the OP to be careful taking the answers in consideration, because something that is valid for the US, may not be valid for the Netherlands. I have heard from several interviewers that asking the salary straight away is generally frowned upon at least in France.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to know a ball park figure for a salary before going for the
>   interview?

Ask the recruiter (whether your working directly with the company or a third party )

```
"What is the salary range for this position?"
```

At this point if you get the run around, follow up with:

```
"In the interest of not wasting your time or mine, I need to be sure 

the salary being offered is something I can work with".
```

If they still don't give you an answer then say:

```
At this point without that information there is no reason to proceed.
```

And **finally** if you get to this point, the recruiter will most likely get the information for you, or just give it to you.

At this point using my strategy you have to **be prepared to walk away.**  Throughout my professional career, there has only been one case where after being persistent that the information was not given.

There really is no point of interviewing with a company in most cases if you don't know with some certainty that **the opportunity will pay a wage that is right for you.**

**Note**:  *Ideally these steps would be taken as part of scheduling the initial face to face interview.*

Answer (score 2):

You're right, you don't want to spend time on a day long interview (especially if you have to use holiday to go to it) without knowing if the salary is appropriate.

Normally you would have an idea from the recruiter/advert what the salary could potentially be, but in this case you do not.  I would recommend contacting the internal recruiter you spoke to and asking what the potential salary range is before the interview.  I'm slightly surprised there hasn't been a conversation about it already (its not just wasting your time, but theirs too, if their salary offer would have been too low for you to move).

I would be surprised if this caused any negativity, but you can be honest and say that you had an interview recently and then found out the pay was too low for you to make the move, and the last thing you want to do is waste either of your time.  This is a reasonable enough request that if you did get any hostility it would be a red flag against the potential new employer anyway.